# how to parse a html file and render it in android

Tags: android, html, parsing

I want to parse a html file, after that, render it in screen without using webview.

But i have no idea about how to do it.

For parsing, maybe I can use jsoup, right? For rendering, I don't know how to do it.

For render, I just mean show all element in screen.

any one can give me advice or example.

thanks your very much.

---

For html parse, i want the smallest one. I don't know whether

jsoup is best one.

About render html, can you give me some example?

thanks.

Comment: what does your html file have? images, texts?

Comment: About html file, include some basic elements. text, link, image, simple css, button.

Comment: I also need draw element in screen. so it is better to have a exmaple, so that i can study it.

Comment: @Raghunandan i have same problem to display html file page wise.using webview.In my html file content both text and images

Comment: why you cant use webview?

Answer (score 0):

See this jsoup documentation if http://jsoup.org/ hope it will help you.

Comment: For jsoup, i think i can use it. I also wan to know how to draw html contents into screen. any example code? thank you very much.

Comment: maybe you can check my code here pay attention to the jsoup.connect() and the library used.  http://pastebin.com/5jZqskdx

Comment: Hi, Raditya Kunianto, i cannot get your code. :(

Answer (score 0):

You must copy **jsoup.jar** file into your project's **libs** folder. Than right click to jar file (into eclipse of course) "**build path/add to buildpath**". Thats it, now you can use jsoup commands.

edit for misunderstanding.

i think this sample will be useful: jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

here is selector list: jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Comment: thanks. I tried jsoup, it can work.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. here is a sample, i think this sample will be useful: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

and here is selector list: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html